# Optimize sql query runtime

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization

I have a query:

```
SELECT `l`.`id`, `l`.`headline`, `l`.`description`, `l`.`image`, `l`.`campaign_id`, IF(l.required_impressions=0,0,1) AS sequence, (IFNULL(ROUND(COUNT(DISTINCT(lc.id)) / COUNT(DISTINCT(li.id)), 3) * 100, 0) * 0.3) + (l.cost * 0.7) AS `scales`, `c`.`name` AS `campaign`
FROM `app_links` AS `l`
INNER JOIN `app_campaigns` AS `c` ON c.id = l.campaign_id
LEFT JOIN `app_link_clicks` AS `lc` ON lc.link_id = l.id
LEFT JOIN `app_link_impressions` AS `li` ON li.link_id = l.id
LEFT JOIN `app_links_categories` AS `lcat` ON l.id = lcat.link_id
LEFT JOIN `app_links_countries` AS `lcou` ON l.id = lcou.link_id
WHERE lcat.category_id IN(3,7,14)
AND lcou.country_id IN(89,147,124,131,259,197,88)
GROUP BY `l`.`id`
ORDER BY sequence DESC, `scales` DESC
LIMIT 6
```

The EXPLAIN query return:
[image]

Do you have any ideas how to optimize the query? Now it take ~0.6 sec, so it's quite long :/

Comment: Remove the `lcat` and `lcou` terms from the query, since they are not referenced? (or replace the `LEFT JOIN` by an ordinary `JOIN`, indeed)

Comment: Is it intentionally that you have `lcou.country_id` used and `lcou` joined by `LEFT JOIN`? The same question for `lcat`.

Comment: @wildplasser: they are used in `WHERE`

Comment: @zerkms: indeed. (BTW: I don't think it will make any defference, since the both appear to return one tuple. It is the outer query + the final sort+ limit which eats the clocktics)

Comment: @wildplasser: it would make difference - if you remove `lcat.category_id IN(3,7,14)` then you could have `category_id` with `NULL` values and with something like `category_id = 42`, which is not desired (assuming the query produces correct results)

Comment: Yes, I know. I also fully agree with your point `3)` : put the conditions where they belong (In the ON clause)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you're referring to `lcat` and `lcou` in the `WHERE` clause it makes no sense for them to be joined by `LEFT` join.

So my proposal is:

1. Change `LEFT JOIN` for `lcat` and `lcou` to `INNER JOIN`
2. Move these 2 joins upper so all `INNER JOIN`s were in the beginning
3. Move `lcat` and `lcou` conditions to the correspondent `ON` clauses (this shouldn't change anything, but would be more readable)
4. Create composite `link_id + country_id` and `link_id + category_id` indexes
5. As you can see - mysql optimizer changed the order for the tables joins, so the `app_links` was joined in the middle and seems like `app_links` is myisam (it's just a guess based on the fact that `campaign_id` doesn't look like a clustered index). If so - try to add compound `campaign_id + id` index for it as well

PS: make the changes above and provide new execution plan

PPS: provide schema for all the tables from the query

Comment: Unfortunately I use Zend Framework and build above query i Query Builder, so I cant reorder all joins (it is depend on the PHP code).

Comment: @BlueMan: at least do everything else and provide execution plan if you have further questions

Comment: I change link_categories order, I change left joins to inner joins. Also I add suggested indexes. Now query run in ~0.08 sec. EXPLAIN: http://tinypic.com/r/23wkx6t/5
Every table are InnoDB.

Comment: @BlueMan: does it need to be even better?

Comment: I'm not sure if it could be :) I run the query on huge database with ~10 mln records. Thanks!